# Capybara::ElementNotFound:

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, rspec2

I am testing my Rails app's sign up form with RSpec and Capybara. When I want to test it I face this error,

```
Failures:

  1) user registration allows new users to register with an email address and password
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Confirmation",          :with => "foo"
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Confirmation' found
     # ./user_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is my form which is a sign up form,

```
<div id="box">
  <div class="block" id="block-signup">
    <h2>Sign up</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :class => "form login"}) do |f| %>
          <% if @user.errors.any? %>
              <div id="errorExplanation">
                <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
                  this post from being saved:</h2>
                <ul>
                  <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                      <li><%= msg %></li>
                  <% end %>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <%end%>
        <div class="group wat-cf">
          <div class="left">
            <label class="label"><%= f.label :email %></label>
          </div>
          <div class="right">
            <%= f.email_field :email %>
            <span class="description">Ex: test@example.com</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group wat-cf">
          <div class="left">
            <label class="label"><%= f.label :password %></label>
          </div>
          <div class="right">
            <%= f.password_field :password %>
            <span class="description">Must contains the word 'yeah'</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group wat-cf">
          <div class="left">
            <label class="label"><%= f.label :confirmation %></label>
          </div>
          <div class="right">
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
            <span class="description">Don't miss any letters</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="group navform wat-cf">
          <button class="button" type="submit">
            <%= f.submit "Sign in", :type => :image, :src => "http://pilu.github.com/web-app-theme/images/icons/tick.png" %>
          </button>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div id="links-sup">
      <h4><%= render "links" %></h4></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my test file is spec/requests/user_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "user registration" do
  it "allows new users to register with an email address and password" do
    visit "/users/sign_up"

    fill_in "Email",                 :with => "user@eample.com "
    fill_in "Password",              :with => "foo"
    fill_in "Confirmation",          :with => "foo"

    click_button "Sign up"

    page.should have_content("Welcome! You have signed up successfully.")
  end
end
```

You have any idea to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error here indicates that it cannot find textbox with label "Confirmation". Here you have problem with html. There is **no textbox with Confirmation label**. You can test by clicking that label "Confirmation", the cursor won't be in the `password_confirmation` textbox.

See the difference why click on "Password" label, the cursor is in the password textbox. That's why there is no error on `password` field.

You could change the markup a little bit to `f.label :password_confirmation`.

When you see the error `Capybara::ElementNotFound`, it simply means it cannot find that element you reference. Therefore you need to check your markup is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there is a confusing point for me. When I look my app html source on the browser, I see <label for="user_confirmation>..</label>. Could this a problem?

Comment: the view that rails generates: "#{modelname}_#{fieldname}" for id, and "#{modelname}[#{fieldname}]" for name attribute. id makes people easy to access from javascript, and name for submit data back to rails.